# Python problem with locating elements [Selenium] [Webdriver]

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, braintree

I am trying to make a python script that will make payment automatically on [this](https://www.audiobooks.com/signup) site. I am able to get credit-card-number input but i can't access expirty month or CVV.

**Code I tried**
I used this to get credit card number field below

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-number']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='number' and @id='credit-card-number']"))).send_keys("0000000000000000")
```

I used same thing to get Expiry month field, like this,

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@id="braintree-hosted-field-expirationMonth"]')))
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='expirationMonth' and @id='expiration-month']"))).send_keys("12/2024")
```

But this code don't work

So what  I want is, I want to detect Expiration field and also CVV field, the method I used can't detect the field.

Comment: there no expirationmonth only expirationdate

Answer (score 0):

if you switch to one iframe you have to swithc to default content before you can interact with another iframe outside the current iframe in which the code focus is use

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-number']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='number' and @id='credit-card-number']"))).send_keys("0000000000000000")
browser.switch_to_default_content()
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@id="braintree-hosted-field-expirationMonth"]')))
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='expirationMonth' and @id='expiration-month']"))).send_keys("12/2024")
```

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'WebDriverWait' has no attribute 'switch_to_default_content'

Comment: @AkibKhan its browser.switch_to updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Frame id was off and the xpath was also off cause no expirationMonth. Also switch to default content.

```
browser.get("https://www.audiobooks.com/signup")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"braintree-hosted-field-number")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='number' and @id='credit-card-number']"))).send_keys("0000000000000000")
browser.switch_to.default_content()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "braintree-hosted-field-expirationDate")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='expirationDate' and @id='expiration']"))).send_keys("12/2024")
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Try switch first, then catch the xpath] Try to switch to the iframe first, then you can identify the column with xpath

Comment: can u give me code snippet? i tried to switch first



WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="braintree-hosted-field-expirationMonth"]')))